# Get the next character after a certain characters position

Tags: c#

I am currently trying to read in a log file that consists of [content]. The message in between the brackets might not necessarily be the same length.

I know that the content will start from character position 28 but I then need a way of doing a substring to only get the content upto the next ]. I.e. if I do a substring it will show content.

I have tried `line.Substring(28, line.IndexOf(']'));` but this doesn't seem to get the next ] after position 28, instead gets the first ] at the beginning of the line.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a `string.IndexOf(char, int)` overload that takes a position to start the search at.

Also, don't forget that `IndexOf` returns -1 if the character could not be found; you may want to check for that before you feed it to the `SubString` method.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Had no idea that was available. :)

Answer (score 0):

If every line has one [content] in it, try: `line.Substring(28, line.LastIndexOf(']')-28);`